# Setting not null when casting data during SELECT INTO

Tags: sql-server

In optimising the speed of my table migrations/transformations (many tables, millions of rows) of csv data I'm using SELECT..INTO rather than creating the table and doing INSERT INTO. From research I believe this to be far faster.

However, I'm having trouble making the fields default to not null after I use a cast.

The following produces not null fine:

```
'' as field1
CASE WHEN field2!='' THEN field2 ELSE isnull(field1,'') END
```

However, when I try to set the size:

```
cast('' as varchar(20)) as field1
cast(CASE WHEN field2!='' THEN field2 ELSE isnull(field1,'') END as varchar(20))
```

Everything is automatically set to nullable.

Is there a way round this?

btw, this could be a moot point because I have a couple of float values in my table and will need to alter the table to make that not null but hoped this would be far less impact than the benefit of not using insert into.

Comment: And why would any of this be an "optimization"? The resulting table will not have any indexes, constraints, triggers, will be put into a default file group, have no permissions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new column with SELECT INTO, you can coerce not-null by wrapping the `CAST` expression in `ISNULL`. The explict `CAST` of the literal determines the data type returned by [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as well as the value inserted into the new column. This provides full control over the resultant column type, length, precision, and scale. Without the `CAST` SQL Server will infer the data type and properties from the specified literal.

Examples:

```
ISNULL(CAST('' AS varchar(20)),'') AS varcharColumn
ISNULL(CAST(0 AS int),0) AS intColumn
```

In the case of an existing column, the source column data type and nullability is used by default. You can similarly coerce a different data type with CAST and/or use ISNULL to change the nullability to NOT NULL.

Examples:

```
ISNULL(CAST(varchar10Column AS varchar(20)),'') AS varcharColumn
ISNULL(intColumn,0) AS intColumn
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought of that. I don't suppose there's a way to make a numeric field not null is there, I'm guessing not...?

Comment: @Neil, if I understand you correctly, just `CAST` the literal as desired. I added that to my answer.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll accept. However my secondary question was more about if you do not want a default value (as it might imply something rather than a string which can be empty) but know all the data is not null so simply want the created column to become not null.

Comment: @Neil, I added more info to my answer for the source column use case.  The `ISNULL` replacement value is only used when the source expression is NULL so the literal value doesn't really matter when no source values are NULL. The only requirement is the literal must be convertible to the source type.